# Making a pivot table across multiple columns of non-numeric data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

The following code generates a dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'user_id': [1,2,3,1,1],
        'account_type': ['google','facebook','apple','facebook','google'],
        'activated': ['y','pending','n','y','y']
    
    }
)

df.head()
```

[image: img]

What I need is to create a pivot table for unique_values in the `account_type` column, which aggregates by the `user_id` column.

Essentially, for each `user_id`, I want to see how many of each types of accounts have a value other than `n` under the `activated` column.

The resulting dataframe should be:

[image: ![img2](]

I'm beat by this so far because I the `pivot_table` function seems to only be able to work with numeric values.

Comment: Depends of data, both answers should return different ouputs, so I suggest test in real data if correct ouput for acepting anwser. Especially if not unique combiantions `user_id, account_type` then there should be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Via `groupby()`, `where()` and `transform()` method:

```
df['count']=(df.groupby(['user_id','account_type'])['activated']
           .transform(lambda x:x.where(df['activated'].ne('n')).count()))
```

Finally use `pivot_table()` and `rename_axis()` method:

```
result=df.pivot_table(index='user_id',columns='account_type',values='count',fill_value=0).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Output of `result`:

```
          apple     facebook    google
user_id             
1           0       1           2
2           0       1           0
3           0       0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column filled by mask compared `activated` for no `n`, and then pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=sum` for count `True`s:

```
df = (df.assign(new= df['activated'].ne('n'))
        .pivot_table(index='user_id',
                     columns='account_type',
                     values='new',
                     fill_value=0,
                     aggfunc='sum')
         .rename_axis(columns=None))

print (df)
         apple  facebook  google
user_id                         
1            0         1       2
2            0         1       0
3            0         0       0
```